# QGIS minimum bounding geometry expression

Tags: qgis, convex-hull

I would like to receive the polygon of a convex hull of a group of points in a layer, grouped by its name. Exactly the same result as the "minimum bounding geometry" tool does.

This needs to be done by expressions in Symbol Geometry Generator in QGIS 3.22.

I tried this expression ...

```
convex_hull(collect($geometry,group_by:="name")))
```

Comment: Which bounding geometry do you mean. "Minimum bounding geometry" tool has four options for bounding geometry -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qt4ul.png

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`oriented_bbox` function does what "minimum bounding geometry" tool does. It returns "minimum oriented bounding rectangle" polygon.

```
oriented_bbox(convex_hull(collect($geometry,group_by:="name"))))
```